# Кодировка БД оракл

Tags: база-данных

помогите решить проблему кодировки.
У меня есть программа, которая создает еxe-шнник, в который зашиты bat-файл и 5 sql-ей для обновления БД oracle.
Все файлы сохранены в кодировке win 1251.
Обновить нужно много серверов с 10 и 11 ораклом. На серверах стоят разные ОС(server 2003 и server 2008)32 и 64бит
NLS_parametrы у всех одинаковые.
в батнике прописываем chcp 1251, но не на всех она отрабатывает и в БД записываются данные с кривой кодировкой(нужно русской).

Comment: добавьте в exe выгрузку в файлы текста который у вас в sql лежит и проверьте кодировку которая получится. Возможно она уже поменялась внутри exe

Comment: в логи пишется уже кривая кодировка

Comment: тогда самый простой выход - не включать запросы в текст exe. Или перед исполнением поменять кодировку текста. Проверьте какая кодировка получилась - подозреваю что UTF-8